# grub preventing access to Ubuntu installation key

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

My Windows 10 based laptop has some unallocated memory I want to install Ubuntu on.

Windows 10 works just fine, but whenever I try to access the Ubuntu installation USB key after reboot, grub minimal prompt appears. The only thing I can do from there is to reboot to windows.

grub is probably a the leftover from a past ubuntu installation

Anything I can do?

Thank you in advance

edit: the USB I'm using is the same grub originally came from and its `.iso` file can pass the md5 check test
edit2: I also tried to format the USB key and recreate the intastaller, but nothing changed

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you get the grub minimal when you boot from Ubuntu USB ?

Comment: yes. selecting the ubuntu USB after boot redirects directly to grub prompt. The same USB was accessible on the same laptop in the past, so I guess grub is the problem

Comment: I think the image file (maybe) corrupted, you can try creating new medium from Ubuntu `.iso` file, I also recommend you to check the integrity of image before burn it to usb, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: thanks, but the .iso file I have used to create the installation USB (from which grub comes from) seems to be ok "md5 check sums are the same"

Comment: How did you create new Ubuntu live installer?  Also link on how to create a  bootable DVD or USB flash drive, using Windows or Ubuntu, Min hardware requirements
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb or 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb
 Or if UEFI only, but you must boot in UEFI mode which you want if Windows is UEFI: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: I downloaded the .iso file for ubuntu 18.10 and used rufus to create the live installer